# Nesting an 'if' statement in a 'for' loop to detect matching/non-matching string in a file

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop

I would like to search a file line by line and print out a given message to the screen when a string is matched and a different message to the screen when the string isn't matched.

This is what I have so far:

A file called **network.txt** that is located in the same directory that the script is running from. This is the contents of the file:

```
am.12345
XXXXXXXX
am.67890
XXXXXXXX
```

This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="network.txt"
for line in `cat $file`
  do
    if [ $line == am.* ]
      then
         echo $line
    elif [ $line != am.* ]
      then
         echo "We couldn't find what you were looking for"
    fi
done
```

This is the output I receive from the bash debug:

```
+ file=network.txt
++ cat network.txt
+ for line in '`cat $file`'
+ '[' am.12345 == 'am.*' ']'
+ '[' am.12345 '!=' 'am.*' ']'
+ echo 'We couldn'\''t find what you were looking for'
We couldn't find what you were looking for
+ for line in '`cat $file`'
+ '[' XXXXXXXX == 'am.*' ']'
+ '[' XXXXXXXX '!=' 'am.*' ']'
+ echo 'We couldn'\''t find what you were looking for'
We couldn't find what you were looking for
+ for line in '`cat $file`'
+ '[' am.67890 == 'am.*' ']'
+ '[' am.67890 '!=' 'am.*' ']'
+ echo 'We couldn'\''t find what you were looking for'
We couldn't find what you were looking for
+ for line in '`cat $file`'
+ '[' XXXXXXXX == 'am.*' ']'
+ '[' XXXXXXXX '!=' 'am.*' ']'
+ echo 'We couldn'\''t find what you were looking for'
We couldn't find what you were looking for
```

But when I run the script, I don't get the expected behaviour:

```
macbook:~ enduser$ ./network.sh
We couldn't find what you were looking for
We couldn't find what you were looking for
We couldn't find what you were looking for
We couldn't find what you were looking for
```

I believe the output should look like this:

```
am.12345
We couldn't find what you were looking for
am.67890
We couldn't find what you were looking for
```

What do I need to change to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `[[ $line =~ am.* ]]`.

Smart-matching, or [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) comparison, uses the Perl `=~` operator, not `==` as you have it coded. [RTFM](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) for details. (Search for `=~`.)